# All my folders and sub-folders index page has been replaced by custom hacker's index page

Tags: php

All my folders and sub-folders index page has been replaced by custom hacker's index page

The image that display when I run my webpage

[image]

Comment: So what do you want us to do?

Comment: How to recover from this attack? My question is, I have 1000+ folders in my online file manager. Every folder contains custom files which has been imploded by hacker. Now I should clear up all the files or there is any other way to recover?

Comment: Restore your files from a recent backup.

Comment: Format your server and restore your data from backup *after* you have fixed / solved the problem that lead to the hack.

Comment: So does each folder contain infected files?

Comment: if it was me i'd: 1) take the site offline; 2) find the security flaw that allowed the hackers to change your site and fix it; 3) delete ALL the files (who knows what they have compromised); 4) restore the site from a backup (or git if you don't have a backup); 5) apply your fix to the site (might be just a compromised password); 6) bring you site online again

Comment: @jeff I will do it but why did it happen? Recently I have added google analytics to my webpage. Whether hackers had a loop hole to pass by through GA?

Comment: @jeroen I'm doing it but I do not want this to repeat again.

Comment: @LewisBrowne exactly mate.

Comment: @WeeZel I have many applications running online.

Comment: I doubt Google analytics is the problem. However, a detailed description of how to perform a security audit of your server is way beyond the scope of StackOverflow. I think Google should be your first stop. If you are using a well known CMS or PHP system, that is a common attack point for hackers, so making sure it stays up-to-date would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a situation like this you will need to weigh the pro's and con's of how you want to tackle this issue. Do you want to maintain uptime whilst you are working on the issue (least effective due to the site could still be being attacked) OR  do you want to completely take the site down to work on the issues (best way to prevent further attack but you will then get down time).

In order to recover from this you will want to get all of your files/folders back to where they are. If you were making regular backups then this will be a breeze, If you weren't. This is the time to grab a coffee and get ready for a S##tstorm.

Whilst recovering your files seems like a quick fix, the chances are that the vulnerability lies within one of those files. Although saying that, the issue could be that your server OS is not up to date and the hacker got in through a dated exploit. The possibilities are endless as to how they have done this.

If it was me in this situation. I would:

- take all the files that you need (unless you have a backup).
- Reinstall server OS / Get new server provider with up-to-date software
- Malware scan all of your files
- Make sure that your Server is PCI compliant (if you are making transactions).
- Once you are all back up and running, i would do a full code review to try and find the vuln.
- Also make sure that you run frequent malware and virus scans with email reporting if something is found.
- Make sure you reset all of your passwords as they are now all compromised.

Comment: But I have around 12 applications running online currently. I have been stacked literally.

Comment: Then i would recommend moving each application one by one away from your current hosting environment. The problem with attacks like this is, they are super time consuming. If you don't put the time in, then chances are, it will happen again.

Comment: Like you said, my primary webpage which has been rectified this morning is now hacked again. I have no hope than migrating my applications from server to another.

Comment: the hackers now have a copy of your site, and probably all the other applications you have running on this server. any usernames/passwords in plaintext are now compromised and any vulnerability in your code is exposed. you should also assume there is code on the machine that will re-hack your site and make it vulnerable again, and don't think it's just the application that looks like it's been hacked that has been affected. oh, and good luck - you will need it

Comment: @WeeZel  I'm gonna pick up important files down from the server to local and try restoring my server backup.

Comment: @Dinesh don't forget to Google the hack, someone else may have been through your pain already and posted some advice online (this happened to a colleague of mine with ransomware, a quick Google found the unlock password)

Answer (score 0):

In my old work, Ukrainian hackers somehow got into the server through an insecure and un-maintained Cake PHP application.

If you have been using Git for version control, you should be able to type

`git reset --hard HEAD; git clean -fx`

Which would restore the files to whatever they were like before the hacker got in. 
You still need to find out *how* they got in though! Good luck!

Comment: Good suggestion mate but unfortunately I didn't use GIT anyway I will keep in memory for future instance.